# GET request on endpoint hosted on Linux VM in Azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I have 2 Azure VMs (Windows, Linux) using same virtual network. Both are able to ping each other using the public ip.

I deployed a java application having its own endpoint in Linux VM and I am using url as:
http://abc.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:42200/rest/

I am trying to send a GET request from Windows VM using Postman and getting below error

[image: Error Logged in Postman]

I already added port number 42200 in inbound and outbound rules of network security groups.
Can anybody let me know what could be the cause of this?
I can provide more details if required.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can troubleshoot with below .
1. Are you able to access your applications url using public Ip address inside linux vm using curl command? 
2. is the default webserver page (http://abc.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:42200) able to accessible outside the VM or inside windows VM?- 
3. check bout VM belongs to same subnet and same security rules applied?

Comment: @GautamSharma 1. I am unable to access curl abc.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com, getting connection refused :80, however port 80 is already open. 2. Unable to access the http://abc.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:42200 outside or inside vm 3. Yes, vm belongs to same subnet with same security rules. --- application have a rest endpoint to be called as http://abc.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:42200/rest/api/<parameters> which should receive get requests and perform actions. Any idea on how to make it work. If I deploy everything locally, it works without issues. But not sure why it is acting weird in cloud.

Comment: @GautamSharma I updated the endpoint url by using private ip of linux instead of public. When I access the url on browser I get Http Error 403:The IP address/hostname is not allowed. The same error is coming up in postman.